# Graph in relation to its independence number.

Tags: graph-theory

I am working on the statement " A graph $G$ is a $nKn$ (collection of $n$ number of complete graph each of order $n$) graph if and only if $\bar{G}$ is $α(G) = α(\bar{G}) = n$ and $(p-n)$-regular , where $p$ is the order of $G$ and $α(G)$ is the independence number of $G$ with $n\geqslant 1$."

The converse part seem to be a confusion. Kindly help me with it.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the meaning of $a(G)$ into your question.

Comment: α(G) is the independence number of G

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question properly.  Can you clarify why the graph $G$ consisting of a 3-cycle and a 4-cycle would not be a counterexample?  It would seem to satisfy $n=3$, $p=7$, but it is obviously not a $3K_3$.

Comment: @WillOrrick The graph you mentioned is 2 regular, not (7-3)=4 regular.

Comment: @Graphth : Hmmm. I had understood that it was $\overline{G}$ that was required to be $(p-n)$-regular, rather than $G$. Perhaps this is the root of my confusion. I'm now not sure that I understand how $3K_3$ is defined. Wouldn't $p$ equal 9 in that case, and $G$ have to be 6-regular?

Comment: @WillOrrick Oh, good point.  Yea, I don't understand what the "$\bar{G}$ is" portion refers to at all.  I read it without the $\bar{G}$ is" portion.  Until the OP tells us what it's supposed to mean, I guess we can't know.

Comment: @Graphth : I had assumed that "$\overline{G}$ is..." meant "$\overline{G}$ satisfies $\alpha(\overline{G})=\alpha(G)=n$ and is $(p-n)$-regular".  If by "$3K_3$" is meant three disconnected copies of $K_3$, then with $G=3K_3$, we have $p=9$, $\alpha(\overline{G})=\alpha(G)=n=3$ and $\overline{G}$ is 6-regular.  So this all seems to fit.  But if $G$ consists of a disconnected $C_3$ and $C_4$, then we have $p=7$, $\alpha(\overline{G})=\alpha(G)=n=3$ and $\overline{G}$ is 4-regular, which seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: @Will: It certainly is a counterexample to the result as stated. I don't know what was intended, but the result is easy if we strengthen the hypothesis to require that *every* maximal independent set in $\overline{G}$ (and hence every maximal clique in $G$) have cardinality $n$.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for confirming that.  I hope that the OP will clarify.

Answer (score 1):

(Extended compilation of comments.)

While it is true that the disjoint union of $n$ copies of $K_n$ has the properties

1. $\alpha(G)=\alpha(\overline G)=n$ (where $\alpha$ is the independence number)
2. $\overline{G}$ is $p-n$ regular (where $p$ is the number of vertices of $G$)

the converse is not true. not every graph with properties 1 and 2. Will Orrick gave the following counterexample in comments: let $G$ be the disjoint union of two cycles $C_3 $ and $C_4$; then $\alpha(G)=\alpha(\overline G)=3$ and $\overline{G}$ is $4$-regular where $4=7-3$.

Brian M. Scott then observed that if $\alpha(\overline G)=n$ is strengthened to

(*) every maximal independent set in $\overline G$ has cardinality $n$

then the conclusion $G=nK_n$ follows. Indeed, (*) says that every maximal clique of $G$ has cardinality $n$. Therefore, every vertex is contained in a copy of $K_n$. Since $G$ is $n$-regular (by virtue of 2), it is a disjoint union of some copies of $K_n$. The condition $\alpha(G)=n$ places the number of the copies of $K_n$ at $n$.